# How react functional component can use object variable which declared behind the usage? (include example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{test.foo}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const test = {
  foo: "foo"
};

export default App;
```

this code is from codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/declaring-variable-test-oixgo

this code run without any issue, I thought in javascript, `const` and `let` are not hoisted, 
so It should be declared and initialized first before It is used (I thought the order of executing code is important) 
But In this case, Although `test` object is behind its usage, This code works without any error.

What has happened to this code?

Comment: Hint: Where does `App()` get called in relation to `test` being declared?

Comment: @charlietfl Do you mean that App and test, both are just declarations, so I don't need to concern the order of code in react? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: In this case yes. You can't generalize it to *"order of code in react"* though

Comment: Thats not related to React **at all**, don't get confused about React stuff and Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions don't try to access variables *until the function is **called***.

The function isn't called before the `const` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

```js
const App = () => {
  console.log("read",test.foo)
};

App()

const test = {
  foo: "foo"
};
```

In React, all code will be read then execute component:

```js
const App = () => {
  console.log("read",test.foo)
};

const test = {
  foo: "foo"
};

App()
```

Comment: `all code will be read then execute component:` so think I need to understand the execution process of react, thank you

Comment: Yes, actually when you save the project in react compiler will combine all of the code and the browser read all of them before render.

Answer (score 1):

> const and let are not hoisted

That's not correct. They are hoisted, it's just that they are hoisted *differently* as compared to how `var` does.

From the [`Ecmascript spec -  13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

> let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the
> running execution context's LexicalEnvironment. The variables are
> created when their containing Environment Record is instantiated but
> may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is
> evaluated. A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer
> is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when
> the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created.

Reason why your code works because `App` function is called *after* `test` object's declaration has already been processed.

To understand this better, consider the following example:

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log(test.a);
};

const test = { a: "Hello" };

foo();
```

Above code example logs "Hello" because by the time `foo` function is called, `test` object's declarations has already been processed.

Now, if we move the `foo` function call above the `test` object declaration, you will get an error.

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log(test.a);
};


foo();

const test = { a: "Hello" };
```

Above code example throws an error because of [`Temporal Dead Zone`](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/understanding-temporal-dead-zone-in-javascript), `foo` function can't access the `test` object. `foo` function can only access `test` object if it is called *after* the declaration of `test` object has been executed during step-by-step execution of the code, which is what happened in the first code example.